# How to put array types in the wsdl definition - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I am new working with wsdl and I'd like to put arrays in my types definition in order to receive in my soap server, a request with them. I have tryed of several ways but I haven't been able.

I have a definition with some strings parameters like shipment_gid, override, Weight, equipment_type and equipmen, but I'd like add other one like an array of objects.

Share my current wsdl definitions:

Node V.:14.16.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <definitions> must be the root of the WSDL document -->
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" 
  xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
  xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
  xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <!-- WSDL TYPES: definition of the data types that are used in the web service -->
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s:element name="MessageSplitterRequest">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="shipment_gid" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="override" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Weight" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="equipment_type" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="equipmen" type="s:string"/>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="stops" type="s:Array"/>
              </s:sequence>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="MessageSplitterResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="result" type="s:string"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <!-- MESSAGES: defines the data being exchanged between the service and client -->
  <wsdl:message name="MessageSplitterSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MessageSplitterRequest"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="MessageSplitterSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MessageSplitterResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <!-- PORT TYPES: defines the complete communication operation (one way/round trip) -->
  <wsdl:portType name="MessageSplitterSoapPort">
    <!-- The operation name must be the same as the one specified in the service object -->
    <wsdl:operation name="MessageSplitter">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:MessageSplitterSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:MessageSplitterSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <!-- BINDING: provides details on how a portType operation will actually be transmitted -->
  <wsdl:binding name="MessageSplitterServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:MessageSplitterSoapPort">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="MessageSplitter">
      <soap:operation soapAction="MessageSplitter" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <!-- SERVICE:  -->
  <wsdl:service name="MessageSplitterService">
    <wsdl:port name="MessageSplitterServiceSoapPort" binding="tns:MessageSplitterServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:3000/wsdl"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just to find a solution with a teammate.

This one way to put arrays in your wsdl definition. In this case I understood that to a better types definition is neccesary to use XSD instead of XML.

Here the example and the web site with a better explanation:
https://www.tutorialworks.com/wsdl/

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="https://spot-b.edgelogistics.com/AutoRateService/">
  <xsd:element name="Stops">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="sequence_number" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="stop_type" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="state_id" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="StopsArray">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="tns:Stops" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="GetLoadAutorate">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="tns:Stops" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="AddBookResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="tns:Stops" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

</wsdl:types>